# Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Key'. What is this in Oh My Posh?

Tags: powershell, psreadline, oh-my-posh

```
Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Key'.
At line:380 char:43
+             if ((Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Spacebar).Function -eq ...
+                                           ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.GetKeyHandlerCommand

Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Key'.
At line:383 char:43
+             if ((Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Enter).Function -eq 'O ...
+                                           ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.GetKeyHandlerCommand
```

This appears everytime whenever I open my powershell. What can I do to fix this?

Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to update the PSReadLine module. Run:

```
Install-Module PsReadLine -Force
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same exact issue. It occurred for me when trying to change my theme in the oh-my-posh init line in $profile. Running `Install-Module PsReadLine -Force` fixed the error, but my theme still didn't change. When editing $PROFILE make sure you put in

> `oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH/ENTER-THEME-NAME-HERE.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression`

and not

> `oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "~/ENTER-THEME-NAME-HERE.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression`

The page is wrong under the powershell tab under the Config syntax paragraph.

Hope this helps.